# Ajax function inside ajaxStop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to use ajaxStop function to call an ajax to render new html element, but after the ajax function finsihed it the ajax repeat itself over and over again, i just need to run this ajax once inside the ajaxStop function.
jQuery code:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: url.build('test/payment/getmethod'),
              cache: false,
              showLoader: true,
              method: "POST",
              success: function(data) {
                if(data!='') {
                  var htm ='';
                  htm += '<div class="payment-method-billing-address">';
                  $.each(data , function(i, method) {
                    htm +=  '<input type="radio" class="required" name="snap-method"  value='+method.value+'">'+method.label+'<br>';
                  });
                  htm +=  '</div>';
                  $( htm ).insertBefore( ".checkout-agreements-block" );
                }
                return false;
              }
          })
          return false;
 });
```

Comment: There's no condition to run the ajax. It runs everytime a request ended. Make a bool when it needs to be stopped. Right there you did an endless loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var callAjax= true;

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
          if (callAjax){
            $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: url.build('test/payment/getmethod'),
              cache: false,
              showLoader: true,
              method: "POST",
              success: function(data) {
                if(data!='') {
                  var htm ='';
                  htm += '<div class="payment-method-billing-address">';
                  $.each(data , function(i, method) {
                    htm +=  '<input type="radio" class="required" name="snap-method"  value='+method.value+'">'+method.label+'<br>';
                  });
                  htm +=  '</div>';
                  $( htm ).insertBefore( ".checkout-agreements-block" );
                }
                callAjax = false;
                return false;
              }
            });
          }
          return false;
 });
```

Flag it when ever it needs to stop calling your function. Right there i just added in the success method. But if you need to only do it once you maybe don't need ajaxStop?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/), you can do your AJAX call with `global: false` in order to not fire `ajaxStop` event.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: url.build('test/payment/getmethod'),
          cache: false,
          showLoader: true,
          global: false,
          method: "POST",
          success: function(data) {
            if(data!='') {
              var htm ='';
              htm += '<div class="payment-method-billing-address">';
              $.each(data , function(i, method) {
                htm +=  '<input type="radio" class="required" name="snap-method"  value='+method.value+'">'+method.label+'<br>';
              });
              htm +=  '</div>';
              $( htm ).insertBefore( ".checkout-agreements-block" );
            }
            return false;
          }
      })
      return false;
 });
```

But you should consider using promises to catch the moment all your previous requests are finished.